# Exception Notifier stop working after upgrade rails 2.3.4

Tags: ruby-on-rails

The exception notifier working fine till yesterday my production server upgrade to rails 2.3.4. please help.

**Error are**

```
wrong number of arguments (3 for 2)
[RAILS_ROOT]/lib/smtp_tls.rb:8:in `check_auth_args'
```

---

### Backtrace:

```
[RAILS_ROOT]/lib/smtp_tls.rb:8:in `check_auth_args'
[RAILS_ROOT]/lib/smtp_tls.rb:8:in `do_start'
  /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/1.8/usr/lib/ruby/1.8/net/smtp.rb:525:in `start'
  /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/actionmailer-2.3.4/lib/action_mailer/base.rb:682:in `perform_delivery_smtp'
  /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/actionmailer-2.3.4/lib/action_mailer/base.rb:523:in `__send__'
  /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/actionmailer-2.3.4/lib/action_mailer/base.rb:523:in `deliver!'
  /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/actionmailer-2.3.4/lib/action_mailer/base.rb:395:in `method_missing'
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**I have managed this myself but still would like to share** 
The problem because smtp library in ruby 1.8.7 have changed. I found solution from [here](http://jira.public.thoughtworks.org/browse/CCRB-187)

so, you

1. rm /lib/smtp_tls.rb
2. ruby script/plugin install http://svn.douglasfshearer.com/rails/plugins/action_mailer_optional_tls
3. remove authtype parameter from vendor/plugin/action_mailer_optional_tls/lib/smtp_tls.rb and change line 33

   check_auth_args user, secret if user or secret